# MYSQL feed query2 with query1 results

Tags: mysql

I have two databases for threads and answers. Each thread has a unique thread_id,
and every answer also has column thread_id, so I know which thread an answer belongs to.

I want to query last 10 answers but also want the title of the thread on each answer.

I tried following:

```
SELECT @variable=thread_id,username,date,answer1  FROM answers_mphp WHERE username=? ORDER BY answer_id DESC LIMIT ?;SELECT title, detail1 FROM threads_mphp WHERE thread_id = @variable
answers_mphp

    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |      answer_id      |     thread_id    |   username    |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |          1          |         3        |   katoge      |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |          2          |         7        |   katoge      |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |          3          |         7        |   katoge      |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
threads_mphp
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |      thread_id      |     title        |   detail1     |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |          3          |   Some title     |      ...      |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
    |          7          |   Some title     |      ...      |
    |---------------------|------------------|---------------|
```

Here last three answers are 3,2,1 and each correspond to a thread_id. I want to get the title of thread_id too in the query result, but answers_mphp does not have the columns title. I try to work with the thread_id here.

I try to avoid working with result in order to prevent multiple sql queries.

Comment: You want *last 10 answers* so why do you set the limit in threads_mphp and not answers_mphp?

Comment: @forpas I fixed it. Was embarrassing mistake.

Comment: Post sample data to clarify what you want.

Comment: @forpas Do you think I should just ALTER the extra columns of threads_mphp into answer_mphp? I really tried to work clean seperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `join` of the tables and apply `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT a.*, t.title, t.detail  
FROM answers_mphp a INNER JOIN threads_mphp t
ON t.thread_id = a.thread_id
WHERE a.username=? 
ORDER BY a.answer_id DESC 
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: I think this solved it! Thank you. Also "WHERE a.username=?"